# Custom actions in facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a comic reader app where I want to create a custom story - "Martin read a comic on AppName".
I was able to create the object "comic" successfully. Facebook would not let me associate the action "Read" with comic so I created a custom action "Reading" with all the verbs modified.

I was able to achieve the story. But when I submitted this for facebook approval, the app was rejected.
It read:

> You’ve submitted a custom action, which isn’t permitted. Please delete
>   this action type and submit a common version instead.

[image]

Is it not possible to associate existing actions with new objects? Or what is the best way to achieve such a custom story?

Comment: You cannot use the verb read with anything else apart from Book or news.